# Progress bar to upload video into youtube?

Tags: c#, video, youtube-api, progress-bar

How to get progress of the video file getting loaded into youtube using Google-Youtube?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a real question. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Resumable Uploads, you can use a listener and add callbacks to track the activity.

1) [Resumable Upload example](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/java/youtube-cmdline-uploadvideo-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/youtube_cmdline_uploadvideo_sample/UploadVideo.java).

2) [Updating Compat Widget with Progress in Android example](https://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/ytdl/ResumableUpload.java).